# How to escape HTML character in angularjs. I have read using ng-blind / ng-sanitize to escape Html, but not able to implement it

Tags: javascript, html, angular, angular11, ngx-editor

I am new to Angular Js.  I have used ngx-editor to make text-area with different formatting Styles. When I am submitting the content I am getting HTML tags along with it. I know these tags are coming whenever I type content in the text-area and use different formatting styles, like to make content bold, italic, h1,h2,h3, etc.

I don't want these tags to display on the browser. Please provide me with a solution and explain why HTML tags are displaying on the browser along with the content.

Code Snippet

component.html

```
 <div class = "NgxEditor__Wrapper" >
                  <ngx-editor-menu [editor]="editor" [toolbar]="toolbar"> </ngx-editor-menu>
                  <ngx-editor [editor]="editor" required placeholder="Write Content" formControlName="contentData"> </ngx-editor>
                </div>
                <mat-error *ngIf="blogForm.get('contentData').hasError('required')">
                    Description is Required!
                </mat-error>
```

component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy, ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';
import { AbstractControl, FormControl, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';
import { Validators, Editor, Toolbar } from 'ngx-editor';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: 'app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['app.component.scss'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
 })
 export class AppComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
 editor = new Editor;
 toolbar: Toolbar = [
   ['bold', 'italic'],
   ['underline', 'strike'],
   ['code', 'blockquote'],
   ['ordered_list', 'bullet_list'],
   [{ heading: ['h1', 'h2', 'h3', 'h4', 'h5', 'h6'] }],
   ['link', 'image'],
   ['text_color', 'background_color'],
   ['align_left', 'align_center', 'align_right', 'align_justify'],
  ];


 ngOnInit(): void {
   this.editor = new Editor();
 }

 ngOnDestroy(): void {
 this.editor.destroy();
}

initializeForm(){
this.blogForm =  this.fb.group({
  contentData: ['', Validators.required],
});
```

}
}

contentData: this.blogForm.value.contentData,

Input

[image: click here to see the input]

Output:

[image: click here to see the output]

```
<p><strong><span style="color:rgb(0, 0, 0);"><span style="background- 
color:rgb(255, 255, 255);">Lorem</span></span></strong><span 
style="color:rgb(0, 0, 0);"><span style="background-color:rgb(255, 255
```

Tags are also coming along with the output.

Answer (score 0):

It's late to give an answer to this, but I was facing the same issue lately.

You have to bind the innerHtml property of a div to the editor content. Then the browser interprets it and it shows up properly formated like in the editor:

```
<div [innerHTML]="editor.html"></div>
```